# to stop a running method

Tags: objective-c

i want to stop currently running method for a short duration..
can i do it without using any thread ?

Answer (score 2):

Split the method into a `myMethodPartA` and a `myMethodPartB`.  Then, at the end of `myMethodPartA`, use the line:

```
[self performSelector: @selector(myMethodPartB) withObject: yourArgument afterDelay: someNSTimeInterval]
```

If you need to pass a bunch of information from `myMethodPartA` to `myMethodPartB`, you can bundle all of that information into an NSArray which you pass as the argument to `myMethodPartB`.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSTimer:

```
- (void)doThing
{
  [self doFirstPart];

  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
           target:self
           selector:@selector(doSecondPart)
           userInfo:nil
           repeats:NO];
}

- (void)doFirstPart  { printf("Hello, "); }
- (void)doSecondPart { printf(" world!\n"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the `sleep()` or `usleep()` functions. There might be convenient methods available on `NSThread` as well, depending what you use exactly (you often work on one thread anyway).

Comment: That's a bad idea on your main thread.  If you do that, the UI will freeze for the duration of the sleep.

Comment: In general I'd agree. But there is no context given. Well, in fact he asks specifically "without using any thread", so all the performSelector: ... are technically spoken out. And he wants to *stop* which the others methods do *not* accomplish!